# Argument captor mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have been doing a bit of reading around argument captor and the more I read about it, the more I get lost. Can someone take the pain of explaining it with an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ArgumentCaptor for stubbing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295891/how-to-use-argumentcaptor-for-stubbing)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to docs, this is deprecated. You should use factory method forClass(Class) to create captors instead to avoid NullPointerExceptions. see [here](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

Example:

```
  ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
  verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
  assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, Rachel but I am more interested in understanding how it works. After reading couple of blogs, I am confused as to what's the right way of using it. So, I'd you could explain it with an example, it would be great. Thanks

Comment: you should read this similar SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295891/how-to-use-argumentcaptor-for-stubbing

Comment: Thank you, that helps. Never came up when I was searching for it.

Comment: The no-arg constructor of the ArgumentCaptor class is deprecated.  ArgumentCaptors themselves are certainly NOT deprecated.  Indeed, they are an extremely useful technique.