# Test argument of a void method with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Is it possible to test the values of an instance passed as an argument to a method that is void using Mockito?

```
public String foo() {
    Object o = new ObjectX();
    o.setField("hi");
    someDao.boo(o);
    return "response";
}
```

boo is void and I want to test that foo sets the field to "hi"

Comment: Clarify your question. Show code.

Comment: Maybe with an `ArgumentCaptor` when verifying the call.

Comment: Since `o` is declared to be an `Object`, it won't have access to the method `setField()`, which I presume lives in `ObjectX`.

Comment: I agree with @Brice. [Use an ArgumentCaptor as explained in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295891/how-to-use-argumentcaptor-for-stubbing). No point posting a duplicate answer here.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you would want to use [doNothing](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing()) method.

```
@Mock
SomeDao someDao;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<ObjectX> captor;

@Test
void test() {
    doNothing().when(someDao).boo(captor.capture());
    foo();
    assertEquals("hi", captor.getValue().getField());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**
this is what JB in my comments is suggesting.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BarTest
{
    @Mock
    private SomeDao someDao;
    @InjectMocks
    private Bar     bar;

    @Before
    public void initMocks()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo()
    {
        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>()
        {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
            {
                ObjectX x = (ObjectX) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                Assert.assertEquals("hi", x.getField());
                return null;
            }
        }).when(someDao).boo(Mockito.any(ObjectX.class));
        Assert.assertEquals("response", bar.foo());
    }
}
```

**This below is my first answer and correct in its own way.**
No it's not possible with Mockito, since ObjectX is a new Object within the void method, to accomplish this with Mockito then you would have to pass ObjectX in as an argument to the method `foo()`. You might want to look into Powermock if your code can't be changed.

```
public String foo(ObjectX objectX) {
    Object o = objectX;
    o.setField("hi");
    someDao.boo(o);
    return "response";
}
```

Test case

```
@Test
public void testFoo()
{
    ObjectX mock = Mockito.mock(ObjectX.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("response", foo(mock));
    Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.times(1)).setField(Mockito.eq("hi"));
}
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. What needs to be mocked and injected is someDao.

Comment: This works because ObjectX is passed as parameter. In my case it is not a parameter