# Mockito's verify method interferes with doAnswer's checks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

When using mocks for unit testing, I often encounter the need to check whether a certain method of the mock is invoked *with proper arguments*. This means that I have to somehow find a way to peek into what gets passed to the method in question. In Spock this can be done using something like:

```
1 * serviceMock.operate(*_) >> { args ->
    def argument = args[0]
    assert expectedValue = argument.actualValue
}
```

With Mockito (and JUnit), the only way I think this can be done is by using `doAnswer` and `verify`, something like:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
  //check arguments here
}).when(service).operate(any(Data.class));
```

Then I have to verify that the operation actually gets called with:

```
verify(service).operate(any(Data.class));
```

The code above, however, interferes with `doAnswer` as if it's an actual call to the method in question. How do I work around this so that I can both verify that the method is called, and verify that the arguments it gets are correct?

Comment: did u try ArgumentCaptor<T> ?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295891/how-to-use-argumentcaptor-for-stubbing) should be useful

Comment: No, I've actually never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito verifies argument values in natural java style: by using an equals() method. This is also the recommended way of matching arguments because it makes tests clean & simple.

```
ArgumentCaptor<Data> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Data.class);
verify(service).operate(argument.capture());
assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getDataName());
```

more refer [here](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15)

I hope this will be helpful

Comment: It keeps telling me that no value gets captured. Do I specify these lines before the actual call, or after?

Comment: just clarification , In this context , u sent Data object to method operate right ?

Comment: You mean in the actual call to the mock? Yes. I have an actual call to `service.operate(actualData);`.