# RxJava2 JUnit testing

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have some troubles with unit testing a RxJava code part. I want to test the method below. It is a presenter method.

```
public void onSearchQueryChanged(String searchQuery) {
    backendService.getShopResultsCount(searchQuery)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(result -> {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                getView().hideShopSearchInProgress();
                getView().displayShopSearchResultCount(result.getSearchResponse().getNumberOfHits());
            }
        }, error -> {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                getView().hideShopSearchInProgress();
            }
        });
}
```

In the best case I would like to mock the `backendService` and test this usecase for specific search queries and with attached/detached view.

I've done some research and I'm aware of `toBlocking()` and `test()` methods. They all assume I have the `Observable` available. I guess I have to split the method somehow. What would be your approach on that?

My stack: RxJava2, dagger, MVP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our project we write code like:

```
Mockito.when(backendService.getShopResult(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Observable.just(Some Data)
```

U can workaround schedulers by:

```
@Inject
Scheduler subscribeOn;
```

And in test pass `Schedulers.test()` or `Schedulers.immediate()`

or u cant use `TestRule` with `RxJavaPlugins.registerSchedulersHook()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all if this is a real MVP project, then you should have `backendService` and `view` somehow injected into presenter. So you can mock them with `Mockito`. [@СергейБоиштян](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41243177/6507689) has provided the way how to do it and how to override `Schedulers`.

Definitely you should test which method of view is called when controlling `backendService` behaviour. That is to be done by [`Mockito.verify(...)`](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/11/mockito-verification.html)

You might also test what output from `backendService.getShopResultsCount(searchQuery)` is passed to `view` by using `Mockito`'s [`ArgumentCaptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295891/how-to-use-argumentcaptor-for-stubbing)

Comment: I know all of that. The question targets RxJava, not the ususal JUnit testing. Overriding schedulers is the way to go.